# Nativescript view model data binding not working for just one page

Tags: javascript, nativescript

Edit: i tested all the other pages in my app by putting an alert in the viewModel to fire ones the page loads, it all fires except this particular page.

It worked yesterday night when i was working, but today, its not. I am saving some data in sql db on this page. i feel its something simple but i need helping figuring this out... i don try hard.

newschedule.js:

```
var Sqlite = require("nativescript-sqlite");
var FrameModule = require("ui/frame");
var createViewModel = require("./newschedule-view-model").createViewModel;
var PickerManager= require("nativescript-timedatepicker");


exports.pageLoaded = function (args) {
page = args.object;
}

exports.onNavigatingTo = function (args) {
var page = args.object;
(new Sqlite("app.db")).then(db => {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS schedules (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, course_id INTEGER, scheduleName TEXT, scheduleTime TEXT, scheduleVenue TEXT, scheduleDate, TEXT)").then(id => {
        page.bindingContext = createViewModel(db, page.navigationContext.courseId);
    }, error => {
        console.log("CREATE TABLE ERROR", error);
    });
}, error => {
    console.log("OPEN DB ERROR", error);
});
   }
```

newschedule-view-model.js:

```
var ObservableArray = require("data/observable-array").ObservableArray;
var Observable = require("data/observable").Observable;
var Sqlite = require("nativescript-sqlite");
var Dialogs = require("ui/dialogs");
var PickerManager = require("nativescript-timedatepicker");



function createViewModel(database, courseId) {
var viewModel = new Observable();
viewModel.schedules = new ObservableArray([]);

viewModel.title = "You have a new lecture";
viewModel.courseId = courseId;
viewModel.scheduleName = "";
viewModel.scheduleTime = getTime();
viewModel.scheduleVenue = "";
viewModel.scheduleDate = "";
viewModel.scheduleYear = getYear();
viewModel.scheduleMonth = getMonth();
viewModel.scheduleDay = getDay();


viewModel.insert = function() {
        database.execSQL("INSERT INTO schedules (course_id, scheduleName, scheduleTime, scheduleVenue, scheduleDate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [this.courseId, this.scheduleName, this.scheduleTime, this.scheduleVenue, this.scheduleDate]).then(id => {
            this.schedules.push(result.text);
        }, error => {
            console.log("INSERT ERROR", error);
        });

    }

viewModel.timeTap = function () {

    var mCallback = function (result) {
        if (result) {

            alert(result);
        }
    };
    PickerManager.init(mCallback,null,null);
    PickerManager.showTimePickerDialog();
}

return viewModel;
}

exports.createViewModel = createViewModel;
```

newschedule.xml: Both the {{insert}} and {{timeTap}} that should fire the event in the newschedule-view-model does not work.

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" 
xmlns:Card="nativescript-cardview"
xmlns:x="nativescript-statusbar"
loaded="pageLoaded" navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo">
<x:StatusBar ios:barStyle="light" android:barStyle="red" />

<Page.actionBar>
    <ActionBar title="Add New Course Schedule">
        <NavigationButton text="Back" android.systemIcon = "ic_menu_back" tap="gobackTap"/>
    </ActionBar>
</Page.actionBar>

<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout class="new-schedule">
        <GridLayout cols="*" rows="auto, auto">
            <Label text="Schedule Name: " cssClass="field-title" padding-top="20"/>
            <TextField id="scheduleName" text="{{ scheduleName }}" cssClass="field" row="1" col="1" />
        </GridLayout>  
        <GridLayout cols="*" rows="auto, auto">
            <Label text="Venue: " cssClass="field-title"/>
            <TextField id="scheduleVenue" text="{{ scheduleVenue }}" cssClass="field" row="1" col="1"/>
        </GridLayout>
        <GridLayout cols="*" rows="auto, auto">
            <Button text="Set Time" tap="{{ timeTap }}" />
        </GridLayout>
        <GridLayout cols="*" rows="auto, auto">
            <Button class="saveScheduleButton" text="Save Schedule" tap="{{insert}}"/>
        </GridLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>

</Page>
```

Comment: what is the most recent changes that made it does not work? As you have said it worked yesterday right?

Comment: @Dinh Le, even reverting the changes does not work. Digging deeper i noticed on this page does not load it's model. i added new pages and it worked... anyway i found another way to do what needs to be done. Thanks.